# Lotus Notes incoming email format

Tags: email, format, lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5. I want to check the format for an incoming email. I want to see if it is in plain text, Rich Text, or HTML (or in whatever format). I have Googled a bit but nothing positive comes up. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt - Enter to open the document properties, then check the tab with all the fields listed: there are a lot of hints that show you, if the mail is Notes Richtext or Mime:

If you find an Item „$NoteHasNativeMime“ with the value 1 then you know it‘s mime. If it has any of these items, then its mime to:

$MimeTrack
MimeVersion

If there is none of the items, then check the first of the Body items:
If its type is MIME Part then you habe a mime mail as well.

In all other cases your mail is native Notes Richtext

Comment: MIME email means HTML email? I have two emails look almost the same. One has the $NoteHasNativeMIME, MIME_Version, and first Body has "MIME format". So I am sure this email is MIME. The other one does not have any of those, but has a 'wBody' field and it has type 'Rich Text'. (First email has this wBody field as well.)

Comment: WBody is a field used in iNotes. It does not necessarily indicate Mime. And yes: Mime mail would be html mail in the context of this question

Comment: You mentioned  HTML, rich text and plain text. Those are the three types in Outlook. Notes is different.

In Notes, MIME does not mean HTML. It means "not Notes native rich text", and it could be literally anything else. Usually it is either plain text or HTML, but you have to actually examine the MIME headers to find out. It might even be both HTML and plain text, because MIME allows sending "alternative" versions of the message content. It could also be empty except for a file attachment or embedded graphic. And by the way, Notes rich text is not the same as Outlook rich text.